# Ionic - Multiple elements fill 100% height of parent <div>

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am building an app in `Ionic` where I am trying to locate four `row` elements and a `button` inside a `div`. The `div` has an `height: 100%` that covers the whole screen, and the content has to stretch to its full-height.

I have tried the following solution, but apparently it is not working:

```
ion-content {
    position: relative; 
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.boxes-container {
    position: absolute; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[This](http://play.ionic.io/app/373993e08bc0) is the complete code. Do you have an idea of what is a possible way to solve it?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: Like this? http://play.ionic.io/app/516728847afe

Comment: Sounds good! Write it as answer and explain what you did to earn the points. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of the `calc` function and viewport units to achieve this layout.

`height: 100vh` will give an element a height equal to that of the viewport.

You have a header element that is 44px in height. Each row has a vertical margin. You can deduct these from 100vh using the `calc` function:

```
.boxes-container {
  height: calc(100vh - 44px - 50px);
}
```

This will give your element a height equal to that of the viewport minus the height of the header element.

You then need to give your four rows and the button a height of `20%` so that they occupy all of the available vertical space in the container.

```
.row {
  ...
  height: 20%;
}

.button {
  height: 20%;
}
```

[Updated live demo](http://play.ionic.io/app/516728847afe)

`calc()` is available in all major browsers and IE>8 ([caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc))

---

An alternative would be to give both `.scroll` and `.boxes-container` a height of 100% and `.row` a height of 20%:

```
.scroll {
  height: 100%;
}

.boxes-container {
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  ...
  height: 20%;
}
```

[Updated live demo](http://play.ionic.io/app/9926defc2c00)

Comment: Actually if the screen changes its dimensions, the section doesn't stretch to the end of `div`. Do you know by any chance how to solve the issue?

Comment: I've just noticed that the button isn't within a row. Each row also has a margin that needs tobe accounted for. Are you actually looking for something like this? http://play.ionic.io/app/516728847afe

Comment: Not exactly. The button should have different dimensions, but the answer satisfies the question :) I am going to edit it.